# What are the various differences in package systems between CL implementations?

Tags: common-lisp, package, symbols

Upon using `(make-package 'test) (in-package test)` in SBCL and CCL implementations, I've noticed that SBCL requires `(cl:defun foo () (...))` or `(cl:describe <symbol name here>)` while CCL does not require any colons or double colons to use built-in symbols. It is my understanding that external symbols must be accessed with one colon, even if they are built-in. However CCL seems to work differently in this respect.

This confuses me somewhat regarding the use of external symbols. Are external symbols supposed to be available without any colons or is CCL just using/importing/inheriting automatically for convenience-sake?

Also, are there any more of these small but significant differences between the implementations regarding symbols and packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The ANSI CL standard does not define which packages are *used* when you create a package**

At some point in time, SBCL deviated from common practice, but still follows ANSI CL standards.

**Using packages**

*Using* packages in some other package means making their symbols available in that package.

You can get a package's *use* list by calling the function `package-use-list`.

It is undefined in the ANSI Common Lisp standard which packages a new package *uses* by default and also if it *uses* any at all.

**Different common practice in implementations**

There are now two common practices in implementations:

- *use* COMMON-LISP and some implementation specific packages. CCL does that.

Example in CCL:

```
? (package-use-list (make-package "FOOBAR"))
(#<Package "CCL"> #<Package "COMMON-LISP">)
```

LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 17 > (package-use-list (make-package "FOOBAR"))
(#<The COMMON-LISP package, 0/4 internal, 978/1024 external>
 #<The HARLEQUIN-COMMON-LISP package, 0/4 internal, 365/512 external>
 #<The LISPWORKS package, 0/4 internal, 226/256 external>)
```

- *use* no package. SBCL does that. If you want a new package to *use* the package COMMON-LISP, then you have to explicitly request that.

Example in SBCL:

```
* (package-use-list (make-package "FOOBAR"))

NIL
```

ABCL:

```
CL-USER(1): (package-use-list (make-package "FOOBAR"))
NIL
```

**Writing portable code**

Thus in SBCL and thus in portable Common Lisp you need to tell Lisp which packages should be *used*. To get the `COMMON-LISP` package *used* and only that package, you need to write:

```
(make-package "FOO" :use '("COMMON-LISP"))
```

**Background**

The original idea in the first Common Lisp was that one could write `(in-package "FOO")` at the REPL and the package was created with sensible defaults and one was directly in that package. The defaults were usually the package for the language (at that time called "LISP") and packages for common extensions (for example with CLOS+MOP, threads, ...).

Later Common Lisp was changed so that IN-PACKAGE did not create a package and it is defined that upon package creation it is undefined which packages are used and it is not required to use any package upon package creation. The SBCL maintainers then thought: instead of supporting common practice (which is not mentioned in the standard), provide a more neutral and predictable behaviour of *using* no package upon package creation.

**Other differences**

Most other differences in package systems in Common Lisp are around extensions to the standard. Examples:

- hierarchical/nested packages
- package prefixes to whole forms (not just symbols)

A bigger and incompatible change provided by some implementations as an option:

- lowercase of all existing symbols and *lowercasing* reader. The standard defines symbols to be internally uppercase by default.

Undefined:

- garbage collection of otherwise unreferenced, but interned, symbols

Comment: Why use `make-package` instead of  `defpackage`?

Comment: For ease of recompilation while developing, it's probably worth looking at uiop's `define-package`. It supports all that `defpackage` does but doesnt barf when you remove a symbol and recompile. Also is has a couple of extra useful options.

Comment: @Sylwester, generally there are differences: defpackage does not evaluate its arguments and it can have compile-time side-effects.